# JbossTS on IBM WebSphere App. server

Tags: transactions, jboss, websphere

I spent time googling to set up JBoss transaction manager in IBM Websphere application server.. I didn't find any hint..
Is it possible ? Reference to article / tutorial would help..

thanks

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

Even if it's possible it's not a best way of handling transactions inside WAS. You should use transaction manager provided by WAS :

1. You paid for this and it's integrated with WAS stack (like JMS/JDBC etc)
2. You have full support in case of problems

Example how to use WAS TM with Spring can be found here:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0609_alcott/0609_alcott.html